# Результат onsubmit формы в новом окне

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма с инпутами

```
<form method="post" action="bla.php" class="x_order_form" onsubmit="yaCounter38229915.reachGoal('order3'); return true;">
<input class="x_client_name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Александр" required>
<input class="x_client_phone" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" required>
<button type="submit">Подтвердить</button>
</form>
```

Мне необходимо чтобы по нажатию на кнопку в текущем окне открылась новая страница, а в новом окне был бы результат onsubmit самой формы. Фокус должен перейти на новое окно с результатом формы.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    for (var i in forms)
    {
        forms[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        forms[i].onsubmit = function()
        {
            window.location.href = 'http://yandex.ru';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Вот такой скрипт открывает результат формы в новом окне, но в текущем не загружает новый url. Подскажите что не так?

Comment: а что вы хотите видеть в новом окне? этот скрипт  не подходит сюда

Comment: в новом окне должен быть bla.php в который форма сделает post запрос

Comment: ничего не понимаю, в bla.php будет результат формы, а в новом окне что надо?

Comment: так в новом окне и нужно чтоб был результат формы, это я сделал, добавив атрибут anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank'); к форме. А вот мне еще нужно, чтобы вместо основной страницы открывался новый url

Comment: 'http://site.com' поменяйте этот линк на ваш

Comment: у меня все работает, открывает bla.php в новом окне и делает переадресацию

Comment: в хроме не хочет работать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52446/discussion-between-l-vadim-and-artem-balan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что хром не обрабатывает переходы по локешин в цикле.
Решил проблему поставив таймОут 500. Теперь все переходит.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    for (var i=0; i< anchors.length; i++)
        {
            anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
            console.log("blank");
        }
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('form'); 
    var nseelink = ('http://cnn.com');
    for(var i in a)
    {
        a[i].onsubmit = function()
        {
            console.log('222222');
            go(nseelink);
        }
    }
    function go(link){
        setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = link;
        },500)

    }
</script>
```